# Interaction between two marking systems (WH + Demon Eye)

Tags: werewolv.es

How does the system respond to a player having two mechanics that mark players? Is it possible? Can it differentiate between two types of marks? What if two different marks are on the same player?

The example here is a Witch Hunter with a Demonic Eye. I believe this is the only possible case at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select an item to use or inspect in werewolv.es, it opens up a new player context menu.

The Demonic Eye shows blighted players within this context menu, which is different to the player list that would show players that have been previously marked by the witch hunter's role ability.